# price regex help

Tags: regex

how to make regex below to detect also prices like just £7 not only everything > 9

```
/\d[\d\,\.]+/is
```

thanks

Comment: Maybe add a bit more detail... What constitutes a price? Do you want to recognize the `£` symbol?

Comment: Please expand on what you want it to match. OPtional-pound-sign digits of points optional-decimal-point-followed-by-two-digits-of-pense, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to match a single digit, you can change it to

```
/\d[\d,.]*/
```

the `+` means require one or more, so that's why the whole thing won't match just a `7`.  The `*` is 0 or more, so an extra digit or `,` or `.` becomes optional.

---

The longer answer might be more complicated.  For example, in the book Regular Expression Cookbook, there is an excerpt:  (remove the `^` and `$` if you want it to match the `2` in `apple $2 each`)  but note that when the number is 1000 or more, the `,` is needed.  For example, the first regex won't match `1000.33`

(unsourced image from a book removed)

Comment: @Will, you removed the image because it is copyrighted material?  Isn't a short excerpt usually ok?  (it probably help sell the book too)

Comment: Sure, its okay to excerpt from a book.  You didn't say what book it was, however.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression would allow `123...3456`... I think you might want something like `(£|$|€)?\d\d+((,|.)\d{2})?`

This will require the source have a currency symbol, and two digits for cents with a separator.

Comment: ok to be frank I would like to be able to use it with things like USD8 for example

Comment: Probably {1,2}, or {1,3} if other currencies need to be supported, is better.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at a regex more like the following.

```
/(?:\d+[,.]?\d*)|(?:[,.]\d+)/
```

Test Set:

> ```
> 5.00
> $7.00
> 6123.58
> $1
> .75
> ```

Result Set:

> ```
> [0] => 5.00
> [1] => 7.00
> [2] => 6123.58
> [3] => 1
> [4] => .75
> ```

**EDIT:** Additional Case added